# How to make a triangle pixellated with GLFW?

Tags: opengl, frame-buffer, glfw

How can one make a triangle look pixelated without modifying the size of the window in GLFW3?

Preferably, I'd like to accomplish this without the use of shaders. For example, by setting the size of the frame buffer to be 1/8th the size of the window.

I've created an [Xcode test project](https://github.com/NatWeiss/glfwTest) for this and tried setting a small window size to create a small framebuffer, then changing the window size to be big afterwards, but the framebuffer size always changes to match the window size.

Example project output:

[image]

Desired output:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Render to a small render target texture ([FBO](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Framebuffer_Object)) first and then render an orthographic quad to the screen using the render target as a texture (with nearest neighbour sampling). There are plenty of tutorials for this such as [this one](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/OpenGL_Programming/Post-Processing).

Comment: I can confirm I got this technique working with a different example project.